# Patching python test methods with unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock

I want to patch a 3rd party library method. In this example its `uuid.uuid4().hex`. I have managed to get the patching work but I wonder if there is a better way to get the same result.

Current solution

```
@mock.patch('uuid.uuid4')
def test_stuff(self, mock_uuid4):
    mock_uuid4.return_value = mock.MagicMock(hex="a83c63e3e2944025abd087c2bd81c46e")
```

Issue with my code is that it does not scale well. What would be a more scalable and "better" approach for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Never came across this library, but maybe you should do something like

```
@mock.patch('uuid.uuid4.hex', return_value="a83c63e3e2944025abd087c2bd81c46e")
def test_stuff(self, mock_uuid4):
    pass
```